# python 'function' has no attribute

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, attributes

I've been pushing this error about all day trying to solve it and decided i need help, i'm guessing its telling me that 'countrynames' is either not defined, not populated or has any values, yet it is used previously in the class 'mysqlbusiness' ok, i am trying to display a simple line of text that shows what item has been selected from a drop down list, the list is populated by a tuple, and a command to apply is selected by a radio button, the message is a polite note !

The TKinter error is this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "S:\python\jon\wrt_toolkit_v5\toolbox_v7.py", line 141, in sendGift
    name = mysqlbusiness.mysqlConnect.countrynames[idx]
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'countrynames'
```

The code snippet is this,

```
class mysqlbusiness:

    def mysqlConnect():
        import pymysql
        sqlUsr = MysqlUsr.get()
        sqlpwd = Mysqlpwd.get()
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.27', user= sqlUsr, passwd=sqlpwd, db='information_schema')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM SCHEMATA")
        schema_names = cursor.fetchall()
        schema_tuple = tuple(schema_names)
        countrynames = (schema_tuple)
        cnames = (countrynames)
        lbox.insert(END, *schema_names)
        # Colorize alternating lines of the listbox
        for i in range(0,len(cnames),2):
            lbox.itemconfigure(i, background='#CEECF5')
        # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
        yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(command=lbox.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        yscroll.grid(row=15, column=6, sticky='ns')
        lbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
        lbox.selection_set(0)
        conn.close()

    # Called when the user double clicks an item in the listbox, presses
    # the "apply" button, or presses the Return key.  In case the selected
    # item is scrolled out of view, make sure it is visible.
    #
    # Figure out which schema is selected, which command (connect or delete) is selected with the radiobuttons, and provide feedback.
    def listConnection(*args):
        idxs = lbox.curselection()
        if len(idxs)==1:
            idx = int(idxs[0])
        lbox.see(idx)
        name = mysqlbusiness.mysqlConnect.countrynames[idx]
        # Gift sending left as an exercise to the reader
        sentmsg.set("%s %s" % (gifts[gift.get()], name))
        lbox.bind('<Double-1>', listConnection)
        mainframe.bind('<Return>', listConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes:

- You are using a class but defined only functions. Don't use classes to create namespaces, Python is not Java and does not *require* classes to be used.
- Your `mysqlConnect()` function doesn't return anything. You cannot refer to local names in functions.
- You didn't actually call the `mysqlConnect()` function.
- You are mixing data retrieval with updating the UI; better to split that out to separate functions.
- You are not extracting the column from the rows; each row result from the database is a tuple with columns (one in this case).
- You are using several variable names for the same result set; there is no need really to make the results a tuple, for example.
- There should be no need to re-bind the event handlers every time `listConnection` is called.

Corrected code:

```
import pymysql

def countrynames():
    sqlUsr = MysqlUsr.get()
    sqlpwd = Mysqlpwd.get()
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.27', user=sqlUsr, 
                           passwd=sqlpwd, db='information_schema')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM SCHEMATA")
    countrynames = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    conn.close()
    return countrynames

def set_countrynames_lbox(countrynames)
    lbox.insert(END, *countrynames)

    # Colorize alternating lines of the listbox
    for i in range(0, len(countrynames), 2):
        lbox.itemconfigure(i, background='#CEECF5')

    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
    yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(command=lbox.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    yscroll.grid(row=15, column=6, sticky='ns')
    lbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    lbox.selection_set(0)


# Called when the user double clicks an item in the listbox, presses
# the "apply" button, or presses the Return key.  In case the selected
# item is scrolled out of view, make sure it is visible.
#
# Figure out which schema is selected, which command (connect or delete) is selected with the radiobuttons, and provide feedback.
def listConnection(*args):
    idxs = lbox.curselection()
    if len(idxs)==1:
        idx = int(idxs[0])
    lbox.see(idx)

    cnames = countrynames()
    # optional, set the lbox again with
    # set_countrynames_lbox(cnames)

    name = cnames[idx]

    # Gift sending left as an exercise to the reader
    sentmsg.set("%s %s" % (gifts[gift.get()], name))

# moved out of the functions
lbox.bind('<Double-1>', listConnection)
mainframe.bind('<Return>', listConnection)
```

Comment: Wowsers! i have been feeling way out of depth and struggling on this project and this shows just how much! I thought i had to create a class because i wanted 'countrynames' to be useable elsewhere outside of the function, i thought i had to define the tuple then take the name i used to define and call that. The amended code you have posted fails to list the tuple in the listbox though and by moving the bind command outside of the definition throws up an lbox undefined error, but i deeply suspect this is because the rest of my code is incorrect based on what you have shown me here. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, there is not enough context to produce working code, I had to stick with the context I had here; but `lbox` appears to be a global in your original code as well (as well as `mainframe`).

Comment: I also don't know what type of object `lbox` *is* so I don't know what kind of values it expects as arguments; it could be that it expects just one argument for example, in which case you need to drop the `*`, or if it does expect multiple arguments, but each is a sequence (rows, say), then you'd need a generator expression to produce those from the simple flat list of country names.

Comment: thats understandable, fyi lbox is simply the reference to the listbox (lbox = Listbox(mainframe, listvariable=cnames, height=10) which was omitted as i was under the impression that we shouldn't post long lists of code here, sorry, The listbox displays the list countrynames derived from the information_schema, thank you for your patience.

Comment: to make your code work (and this is where i go the original class idea from) this line mysqlbutton=ttk.Button(mainframe, width=18,text="MySql connect:",command=countrynames) needs to call countrynames but then also call set_countrynames_lbox to populate the listbox (lbox) but i can find no instance of calling two functions in order from one action (command=)

Comment: You can use a *third* function to call the other two. Or use a `lambda` function; an anonymous function that can only contain one expression: `command=lambda *args: set_countrynames_lbox(countrynames())`, or it could make sense for  `set_countrynames_lbox()` to call `countrynames()` itself.